# Need help clarifying the Supremum definition.

Tags: real-analysis

Here the definition from Rudin’s:
**Definition:** Suppose S is an ordered set, E is a subset of S, and E is bounded above. Suppose there exists an alpha in S with the following properties:

(i) alpha is an upper bound of E
(ii) If gamma < alpha then gamma is not an upper bound of E

Then alpha is called the least upper bound of E.

So I have an issue understanding property (ii). Suppose we are working with the set       E = {1,2,3,4,5} which is a subset of the Reals. Okay so 6 is a clear upper bound of E. But 5.5 < 6. And by that second property, 5.5 cannot be an upper bound, but isn’t it?

Comment: the supremum will be $5$

Comment: 5.5 is an upper bound. It just means that it is NOT the least upper bound for that set. So, property (ii) is a condition to define the least upper bound.

Comment: @js9 oh I see so it’s like a condition you keep checking until you get to that least upper bound